# Windows Forms - ShowDialog with a parent - why doesn't clicking on the parent activate the dialog when main window is maximized

Tags: c++, winforms, showdialog

I'm seeing non-standard behavior (as compared to tools like Word and Visual Studio 2013) in my C++ Windows Forms application.  We use Application::Run and then ShowDialog to show various modal dialogs.  When one of the modal dialogs is up and I place another application window partially in front of the modal dialog, I can click on part of the modal dialog and it brings it back into the foreground as I expect.

However, if I instead click on part of the main window (shown with Application::Run) the modal dialog isn't brought to the foreground.  This makes it hard to bring my application back so I can work on it.  Ideas?

A simple MFC app created in VS2013 works as it should too.  You can witness this with the About box which is shown with DoModal.  I would have expected ShowDialog and DoModal to be equivalents.  A simple C++/CLI or C# winforms application acts fine.

And this only happens in out application when our main window is maximized.

Comment: Are you properly setting the [Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) property for the dialogs being shown? This property should be set to reference the parent window for every dialog.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it, never heard this complaint before.  Repro code is required.

Comment: Some more information: 
* this only happens when our main window is maximized
* I cannot reproduce this in a sample application (using C++/CLI or C#).
* Can't post our real application of course.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that is caused by our use of the Syncfusion UI libraries. They will be fixing the bug.